# rails rspec update_all method works in controller but doesn't in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

** controller

```
puts merchants.first.is_blocked // 1

Merchant.update_all( {:is_blocked => 0}, "mch_id IN (#{@merchants.map(&:mch_id).join(",")})" )

puts merchants.first.is_blocked // 0, so it works
```

** rspec

```
expect {
  get :update_merchants, params
}.to change { merchant_1.is_blocked }.from(1).to(0)

// result should have been changed to 0, but is now 1
```

i don't know the reason why "update_all" method works in controller and doesn't work in rspec

Comment: In your spec, what if you change it to `merchant_1.reload.is_blocked`?

Comment: i applied 'merchant_1.reload.is_blocked'. then i got an error that name of 'no implicit conversion of nil into Hash'. **PS : 'merchant_1' is factory that initialized is_blocked column with 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, your update_all line is pretty nasty. Assuming `@merchants` is an AREL query with the conditions required to locate the merchants you want to update, please consider converting it to this:

```
@merchants.update_all(is_blocked: 0)
```

If @merchants is simply an array of records, then use this:

```
Merchant.where(id: @merchants.map(&:id)).update_all(is_blocked: 0)
```

Secondly, a `GET` request should **NEVER** modify the database. Consider changing this to a `PUT` request.

Finally, if your `merchant_1` instance variable was created/fetched before calling your method, your test still has the pre-change value. You either need to re-fetch it, or call `reload` on it before you'll see the updated values.

```
expect {
  get :update_merchants, params
}.to change { merchant_1.reload.is_blocked }.from(1).to(0)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.

i changed the request type from 'get' to 'put',
and applied 'merchant_1.reload.is_blocked'.

then i got an error that name of 'no implicit conversion of nil into Hash'.

**PS : 'merchant_1' is factory that initialized is_blocked column with 1.

Comment: i solve this problem with `@merchants.each do |merchant| merchant.update_attributes({is_blocked: 0}) end`.
i don't know what is the difference between update_attributes and update_all,
but update_attributes works well.

Comment: That was most likely a mistake on my part assuming that your @merchants would be an AREL object. I've provided a modified update_all statement which will work with a plain array of merchant objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to update the `is_blocked` attribute on all merchants should read like this:

```
Merchant.where(id: @merchants.map(&:id)).update_all(is_blocked: 0)
```

To answer your question in your comment on @Jon's answer (about the difference between `update_all` and `update_attributes`):

- `update_all` will run one SQL query directly in the database to update the data.
- `update_attributes` runs one SQL query per object instance that you run it on.

That said, `update_all` is much more efficient when you use it because the database does all of the work, and it's good at mass `UPDATE` operations like that (unlike looping through a Ruby array and running individual SQL queries for each record).

Then you need to make sure that you're reloading your `merchant_1` in your spec to bust Rails's request-level query cache on that object:

```
expect {
  get :update_merchants, params
}.to change { merchant_1.reload.is_blocked }.from(1).to(0)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer chris. i tried your solution which is `Merchant.where(id: @merchants.map(&:id)).update_all(is_blocked: 0)` but it still doesn't work. is_blocked column is not updated. i think update_all method is more proper in this situation, but i don't know why update_all method can't update active-record column.

Comment: Is it not reflecting the updated data within your app or within the spec?